# Does a Hamiltonian cycle on a graph with $n$ vertices always have $n$ edges?

Tags: graph-theory

We know that a Hamiltonian cycle does not repeat vertices. Hence, does not repeat edges. So can I say that **"a Hamiltonian cycle on graph of $n$ vertices, is a simple cycle with $n$ edges"?**

Comment: Since every vertex must be visited exactly once, and we must return to the start-vertex, we must actually have $n$ edges , so this is a correct statement.